# Adding various ViewGroups to one Android Layout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-view

I have an Android 3.0 Application for Tablets. On this application I have to insert several ViewsGroup on a layout, and each of these ViewsGroup has several views.
Here is the onCreate code of the Activity:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    params = new LayoutParams(500, 600);
    ViewGroup v1 = new Bar(this);
    this.addView(v1,params);
    ViewGroup v2 = new Bar(this);
    this.addView(v2,params);
```

This Bar class extends ViewGroup, and has several views inside it. The problem is that only the Views of the first ViewGroup (v1) are being shown on the screen. But I can see that it add both ViewGroup to the content, since for example I can set the background of the second one and i will see the results.  But the Views that are inside the second ViewGroup are not being drawn on the screen. I tried to change the order, v2 first, and all views inside v2 got drawn while the ones in v1 didn't. I think it may have some to do with the onLayout method inside the Bar class, which I'll put below:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    for(int nI = 0; nI < this.getChildCount(); nI++){
        this.getChildAt(nI).layout(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    }

}
```

Does this method has any problems?

I' using a LinearLayout by the way.

```
<LinearLayout android:background="#C6D7D2" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the type of parent layout? How should the bars be arranged in the parent. Edit your post and add a snapshot. or a prototype img, if u have

Comment: Sorry but I cant post any pics. The bars are components of a bargraph, and I'm using a plain LinearLayout. <LinearLayout android:background="#C6D7D2" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
    </LinearLayout>  . Its simply a bargraph what I'm implementing, but each bar is a ViewGroup, and inside of each of them I have several TextViews to display the values of the Bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override onMeasure() also. You need to set the setMeasuredDimension(w,h) there. w and h are bar's height and width that you get after adding all its childrens dimensions.

Comment: By doing that not even the Views from the first ViewGroup are appearing. I really dont understand this method.

Comment: OnLayout is used to arrange child views within the viewgroups bounds. putting a screen snapshot in your post will give a better idea.

Comment: Are you overriding onMeasure() also. need to set the `setMearsuredDimension(w,h)` there. w and h are bar's height and width that u get after adding all its childrens dimensions.

Comment: not overriding the onMeasure method was the problem. Thank you very much! But i actually used my onLayout method, not the one you posted as an answer. So please change the answer to this comment above. Thank you